# How to save a octree to a file using open3d.io.write_octree?

Tags: python, open3d

I tried to save an octree in a file with open3d.io.write_octree.

```
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np
from open3d.web_visualizer import draw
from numpy import savetxt

if __name__ == "__main__":
    N = 2000
    armadillo_data = o3d.data.ArmadilloMesh()
    pcd = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh(
        armadillo_data.path).sample_points_poisson_disk(N)
    # Fit to unit cube.
    pcd.scale(1 / np.max(pcd.get_max_bound() - pcd.get_min_bound()),
              center=pcd.get_center())
    pcd.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(np.random.uniform(0, 1,
                                                              size=(N, 3)))
    print('Displaying input pointcloud ...')
    #draw([pcd])

    octree = o3d.geometry.Octree(max_depth=4)
    octree.convert_from_point_cloud(pcd, size_expand=0.01)
    print('Displaying octree ..')
    #draw([octree])
    
    o3d.io.write_point_cloud("copy_of_fragment.pcd", pcd)

    o3d.io.write_octree("octofile.oct", octree)
```

But this does not work, write_point_cloud works fine but write_octree does not.

Anyone used this function ? Is there something that I am missing here ?

I am trying to create a file like below in the end.

[octree.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtMGv.png)

Thanks for the valuable feedbacks in Advance.

Comment: [Could you please not post the data (`octree.txt`) as an image but rather as text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: The content of the octree.txt ' -0.3875 -0.3875 0.4625 0.307692
-0.3625 -0.3875 0.4625 0.307692
-0.3875 -0.3625 0.4625 0.307692
-0.3625 -0.3625 0.4625 0.307692
-0.3875 -0.3875 0.4875 0.307692
-0.3625 -0.3875 0.4875 0.307692'

Answer (score 0):

I choose to use octomap library instead of open3d which has many built in options for OcTree.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

After trying different file extensions, I successfully wrote the octree to a file with the following code, although the json content seems far from the txt content you provided.

```py
o3d.io.write_octree("octree.json", octree)
```

If the error in the terminal says *[Open3D Warning] Writing Geometry::Octree failed: Unknown file extension*, my answer may be helpful to you.